# Многоразовое нажатие на кнопку Django

Tags: python, django

Есть страница с формой на Django. При нажатии на кнопку "сохранить" все происходит нормально, но, если продолжить нажимать на нее во время загрузки страницы, форма будет сохранятся то количество раз, сколько вы нажали, заместо одного положенного.
Вопрос: как исправить? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Сделать флаг `true`, если кнопка уже была нажата ранее и не ставить флаг в `false`, пока этого не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего отключать кнопку отправки на клиентской стороне с помощью javascript:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'some_form_handler' %}">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" id="submit">
</form>

<script>
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        this.disabled = true;
    });
</script>
```

Но можно подстраховаться и на бэкенде, набросав middleware типа такого:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.cache import caches

def drop_burst_middleware(get_response):
    cache = caches['post-requests']

    def middleware(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            token = request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken')
            if token:
                if cache.get(token, False):
                    response = HttpResponse('Не надо жать на кнопку по нескольку раз!')
                else:
                    cache.set(token, True)
                    response = get_response(request)
                    cache.set(token, False)
                return response
        return get_response(request)
    return middleware
```

Естественно, что лучше придумать какую-то более дружелюбную реакцию.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо за оперативный ответ!)